# Argument - command prompts c++

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to finish a part of a program where I have to find the last n-1 words in a vector string and shift the next word in source into the end of the vector string. Here I'm trying to write the function for 'findAndShift' and use arguments from another program to use it.

This is my part of the program.

```
void findAndShift(vector<string>& ngram, string source[],int sourceLength) {
    if (argc == 2)///default command prompt...not declared?
    {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open(argv[1], ios::in);
        if (infile.fail())
        {
            cout << argv[0] << ": "<< argv[i] << "I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //get length of n
            infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
            const int sourceLength = infile.tellg();

            int n = 0;
            string word;
            ngram = rand() % sourceLength;
            while (!infile.eof())
            {
                infile >> source;
                ++n;
                if(counter == ngram);
                    word = n;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Here's the program I have to use for mine.

```
 string source[250000];
 vector<string> ngram;
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     int n, outputN, sl;
     n = 3;
     outputN = 100;
     for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
         if (string(argv[i]) == "--seed") {
             srand(atoi(argv[i+1]));
         } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--ngram") {
             n = 1 + atoi(argv[i+1]);
         } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--out") {
             outputN = atoi(argv[i+1]);
         } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--help") {
            help(argv[0]);
            return 0; }
     }
     fillWordList(source,sl);
     cout << sl << " words found." << endl;
     cout << "First word: " << source[0] << endl;
     cout << "Last word:  " << source[sl-1] << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         ngram.push_back(source[i]);
     }
     cout << "Initial ngram: ";
     put(ngram);
     cout << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < outputN; i++) {
         if (i % 10 == 0) {
             cout << endl;
         }
         //put(ngram);
         //cout << endl;
         cout << ngram[0] << " ";
         findAndShift(ngram, source, sl);
     } }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: and whats the problem?

Comment: It's only visible in `main`.

Comment: pass argc into findAndShift as an argument?

Comment: @JasonL argv is also need to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass more argument in your program argc and argv[] as argc is just a parameter for main function and hence is not visible in other function.

Here is your modified code.

```
void findAndShift(vector<string>& ngram, string source[],int sourceLength, int argc, char argv[0], argv[1],argv[i]){
    if (argc == 2)///default command prompt...not declared?
    {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open(argv[1], ios::in);
        if (infile.fail())
        {
            cout << argv[0] << ": "<< argv[i] << "I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //get length of n
            infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
            const int sourceLength = infile.tellg();

            int n = 0;
            string word;
            ngram = rand() % sourceLength;
            while (!infile.eof())
            {
            infile >> source;
            ++n;
            if(counter == ngram);
             word = n;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

your main code

```
string source[250000];
 vector<string> ngram;
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int n, outputN, sl;
   n = 3;
   outputN = 100;
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
     if (string(argv[i]) == "--seed") {
       srand(atoi(argv[i+1]));
     } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--ngram") {
       n = 1 + atoi(argv[i+1]);
     } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--out") {
       outputN = atoi(argv[i+1]);
     } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--help") {
       help(argv[0]);
 return 0; }
   }
   fillWordList(source,sl);
   cout << sl << " words found." << endl;
   cout << "First word: " << source[0] << endl;
   cout << "Last word:  " << source[sl-1] << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     ngram.push_back(source[i]);
   }
   cout << "Initial ngram: ";
   put(ngram);
   cout << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < outputN; i++) {
if (i % 10 == 0) {
  cout << endl;
}
//put(ngram);
//cout << endl;
cout << ngram[0] << " ";
findAndShift(ngram, source, sl, argc,argv[0],argv[1],argv[i]);
 } }
```

I haven''t tested it.
If it still not work try to use char * in argument list of findAndShift

Hope it helps....